# CasperJS input change Event Triggering

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, dom-events, onchange, casperjs

I'm trying to edit an input field outside of a form with CasperJS, then trigger whatever event is associated with that change and get the site to reload.

Upon some investigation, it seems that just loading the page produces an 'Operation Canceled' resource error (code 5).

The website is [here](http://cat.marketnews.usda.gov/cat/?shortcut=snapshot).

And here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var commodity = 'Pears'.toUpperCase();

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1440,
        height: 900
    }
});

//HANDLE AND ECHO each of resource.error, page.error, remote.message, and casper.page.onResourceTimeout

var USDA_URL = 'http://cat.marketnews.usda.gov/cat/?shortcut=snapshot';
casper.start(USDA_URL);

casper.wait(7000, function() {
    this.withFrame('dashboardDisplay', function() {
        this.withFrame('dashboardTimePeriodDisplay', function() {
            this.sendKeys('.rcbInput', commodity, {keepFocus: true});

            //INSERT ONE OF THE OPTIONS HERE
        });
    });
});


casper.wait(7000, function() {
    this.capture('after_change.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I've tried four different approaches, based primarily on what works when I'm just browsing the site.

### Approach 1: Clicking the Dropdown

```
this.click('li.listItem[title="' + commodity + '"]');
```

Selecting the correct list item seems like it should work, but I believe this query fails and the rest of the code does not execute, including the `capture()`. This option results in a second 'Operation Canceled' resource error.

### Approach 2: Clicking the Result Button

```
this.click('.actionBtn');
```

Clicking when the commodity is half-typed on the website causes the list to be refreshed and the change to be triggered. It doesn't in this case.

### Approach 3: Hitting Enter

```
this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Enter);
```

Hitting enter when the commodity is typed in causes the change to be triggered when actually browsing the site, but again, not with CasperJS. (That's also why I have `{keepFocus: true}` in the `sendKeys()`.)

### Approach 4: Triggering the Change Manually

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('rcbInput')[0];
    var evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
    evt.initUIEvent("change", true, true);
    select.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Finally, I went the javascript way and tried to trigger a change event manually. `select` is the correct object, but the change again does nothing. I also tried to use an `HTMLEvent` instead of a `UIEvent` but that actually gave a javascript error (specifically, a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error on the `initUIEvent()` line because apparently `evt` is undefined at that point).

### In Conclusion...

Only the first approach results in an actual error; all the others just don't work.

Because there are so many different issues here, I assume each of my approaches is just slightly off. Any hints on any of them, just to get this to work, would be greatly appreciated. Also a totally new method is fine.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1. I was registered for most of those in my original code, but I have registered for all of them now and have edited the approaches to be more specific on the error side. In short, just loading the page causes a resource error; approach 1 causes a second one. None of the other approaches causes an error that these listeners hear.

Comment: What's the resource error? Can you show it, because this is likely the reason it doesn't work. Anyway, you should make sure that you actually switched to the correct frame.